# Why JS saves difference date in storage?

Tags: javascript

I have variable `formValuesChanged` that contains the following data:

[image]

Then I save this data to storage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("filters", JSON.stringify(formValuesChanged));
```

Then if explore session storage I see this object but with different `date`:

```
{ classNumber: 2
  classSuffix: 5772436057100
  date: "2018-09-23T21:07:47.043Z"
  teacher: 25203
  type: "teacher"
}
```

Why does JS save wrong date?

Comment: Your first code example is a syntax error. That date string should be quoted as a string.

Comment: It is right, I copied that from Chrome console. therfore

Comment: No it is not. Copy it *back* to the Chrome console and see if it runs.

Comment: Okay, I will provide now screen

Comment: Also note that the second snippet does not have a timezone associated it, while the first one does (+4).  And 21 + 4 is 01:00 the next day.  Coincidence?

Comment: Look it's simply true that `Mon Sep 24 2018 01:07:47 GMT+0400 (Azerbaijan Standard Time) {}` is not a valid JavaScript expression, and the right-hand side of a property clause in an object initializer must be an expression.

Comment: Okay, then how to save date right to storage ? For example this: `Mon Sep 17 2018 01:07:47 GMT+0400 (Azerbaijan Standard Time)`

Comment: @OPV you use the [`Date.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) method.

Comment: Look, this gives me `Object` in console: `console.log(typeof this.startWeekDate);`. But this: console.log(this.startWeekDate); gives this: `Mon Sep 17 2018 01:07:47 GMT+0400 (Azerbaijan Standard Time)`. What is wrong here?

Comment: How to save simple date like var d = new Date() in storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no date type in the JSON format, it is a bit of a pain but if you want to store a date in a string format you will need to parse it when you read it back.

```
let obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("filters"));
let objWithDate = { ...obj, date: new Date(obj.date) };
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say it's "stupid"; dates are very complicated, certainly vastly more so than any other JSON type.

Comment: I have added screen of `formValuesChanged`

Comment: I try to store this format date: `Mon Sep 17 2018 01:07:47 GMT+0400 (Azerbaijan Standard Time)`. it is console result

Comment: Problem is not to parse, problem that I have incoming date, but when I store that it has another date

Comment: How to save simple date like `var d = new Date()` in storage?

Comment: It has another date because it is being stored in UTC time, that is what the Z at the end means. The date will be in your local time when read back. Try it.

Comment: Personally I'd store the milliseconds version of the date if I had to.  `getTime()` will get the milliseconds for the date, and then when you need to turn it back into a Date, you just `new Date(milliseconds)` and wha la.